# tesseract-OCR implementation PHP

Tags: php, windows, ocr, tesseract

I want to run tesseract-OCR in PHP. I want to develop a web api for image to text conversion. Kindly suggest a way. I tried this command:

```
<?php
shell_exec("c:\xampp\htdocs\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe a:\lool.jpg a:\out.txt");
echo "edede";?>
```

but there is no output in a:\ directory
teseract is working fine from command prompt and shell_exec is also working fine in opening other executables